# sum counts across multiple days and group by hour

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, group-by, knex.js

I am trying to group records by hour across multiple days using Knex. So, for example, 9AM would be:

```
{
  hour: 9AM, // for days 12/11, 12/12, 12/13
  count: 10 // 10 Ids total over those days for hour 9AM
}
```

Given the records in this snapshot, how can I aggregate them into `hour` buckets across multiple days?

[image]

If I output the query results, you can see two separate results for `19:00` for `12/12` and `12/13`. These two days' counts need to be summed into one `hour 19:00` grouping:

```
ROWS [ anonymous {
    session_ids: [ 3200 ],
    hour: 2016-12-12T14:00:00.000Z,
    count: '1' },
  anonymous {
    session_ids: [ 3201 ],
    hour: 2016-12-12T15:00:00.000Z,
    count: '1' },
  anonymous {
    session_ids: [ 3203, 3202 ],
    hour: 2016-12-12T19:00:00.000Z,
    count: '2' },
  anonymous {
    session_ids: [ 3204, 3205 ],
    hour: 2016-12-13T19:00:00.000Z, // This count should be aggregated into the `19:00` grouping above
    count: '2' } ]
```

**My current query:**

```
var qry = db.knex
  .select(db.knex.raw("array_agg(t2.id) as session_ids, date_trunc('hour', t2.start_timestamp) as hour"))
  .count('*')
  .from('sessions as t2')
  .groupByRaw("date_trunc('hour', t2.start_timestamp)")
  .orderBy(db.knex.raw("date_trunc('hour', t2.start_timestamp)"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `EXTRACT`, not `date_trunc`:

```
var qry = db.knex
  .select(db.knex.raw("array_agg(t2.id) as session_ids, extract('hour' from t2.start_timestamp) as hour"))
  .count('*')
  .from('sessions as t2')
  .groupByRaw("extract('hour' from t2.start_timestamp)")
  .orderBy(db.knex.raw("extract('hour' from t2.start_timestamp)"));
```

---

`date_trunc` truncates a timestamp to the specified precision (meaning the `GROUP BY` won't work, as the days of two timestamps with the same 'hour' field may still be different):

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', NOW());
┌────────────────────────┐
│       date_trunc       │
├────────────────────────┤
│ 2016-12-18 19:00:00+01 │
└────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

while `EXTRACT` fetches the specific field you asked for:

```
SELECT extract('hour' from NOW());
┌───────────┐
│ date_part │
├───────────┤
│        19 │
└───────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: @Growler: missed the `date_trunc` in the `ORDER BY` clause. I fixed it.

Comment: This is great. What is `date_trunc` good for then? And what do you mean by `fetches the specific field you asked for`? Doesn't `trunc` also yield a `19th` hour?

Comment: @Growler: You can see what `date_trunc` returns in the `"hour"` fields in your question. It can be useful when you want to compare 2 timestamps with a bit of leeway: for instance if you only want to compare dates up to the minute, you could use `date_trunc('minute', ts) = date_trunc(…)`, which would discard second/millisecond precision (setting them to 0 on both side before checking for equality).